# Is there a way to get number of objects in a google cloud storage bucket using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I need to get the number of files in a bucket of GCS.
I don't want to use `list_blobs` to read them one by one and increase a counter.
Is there something like a metadata we can query?

I need to download all the files in the bucket and process them. now I want to do it using threads so I would need to separate files to groups somehow.
The idea was to use `list_blobs` with `offset` and `size`, but in order to do that I need to know the number of total files.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do a single metadata query to get the count. You could run a command like:

```
gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/** | wc -l
```

but note that this command is making a number of bucket listing requests behind the scenes - which can take a long time if the bucket is large, and will cost based on the number of operations it makes.

Answer (score 1):

I know the original question did not want to use `.list_blobs()` to count the number of files in a bucket, but since I didn't find a different way, I'm posting it here for reference, since it does work:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs_list = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_or_name='name_of_your_bucket')

print(sum(1 for _ in blobs_list))
```

`.list_blobs()` returns an iterator, so this answer basically loops over the iterator and counts the elements.

If you only want to count the files within a certain folder in your bucket, you can use the `prefix` keyword:

```
blobs_list = storage_client.list_blobs(
    bucket_or_name='name_of_your_bucket',
    prefix='name_of_your_folder',
)
```

FYI: this question suggests a different method to solve this:
[How can I get number of files from gs bucket using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300498/how-can-i-get-number-of-files-from-gs-bucket-using-python/72000980)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a command line answer, you can use

```
gsutil du gs://pub | wc -l
```

Answering here as this was the first link I got when I searched.
References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18986955/6733421
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du